# Estimators that are superefficient on a dense set

Tags: regularization, asymptotics, parametric

In Chapter 8 of van der Vaart's *Asymptotic Statistics*, it is shown that (under weak regularity conditions) an estimator can be "superefficient" on at most a set of Lebesgue measure zero (Theorem 8.9). He then considers (in Example 8.12) Stein's shrinkage estimator. Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be independent, identically distributed samples from a multivariable normal distribution with mean $\theta$, covariance matrix the identity, and dimension $k$ at least $3$. Consider the estimator
$$
T_n = \overline{X}_n - (k-2) \frac{ \overline{X}_n}{n \| \overline{X} \|^2}.
$$
van der Vaart shows that $T_n$ achieves the usual normal parametric asymptotic efficiency bound when $\theta\neq 0$ and beats it in $L^2$ norm at $\theta =0$ (and under local alternatives).

Hence, if one only cares about $L^2$ norm, the shrinkage estimator is in a sense strictly better (asymptotically) than the usual sample mean. I am curious about whether $T_n$ can be improved further, as evaluated by these asymptotic criteria.

Does there exist an estimator in this normal mean problem that is "superefficient" in $L^2$  on a dense set of $\mathbb{R}^k$ (and under local alternatives to every point on this dense set), and achieves the asymptotic parametric efficiency bound for other parameter values? If so, has the construction appeared in the literature anywhere?

Comment: There are certainly estimators that beat James-Stein if that helps.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. Could you please suggest a reference?

Comment: Start here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%E2%80%93Stein_estimator#Improvements and see the indicated references for that section. MLE is known to be inadmissible because of the James-Stein estimator, but James-Stein is itself inadmissible, and the identified thing that beats it there is in turn inadmissible.